# Converting string of number to Hex, Binary, and Decimal

Tags: java, arraylist, binary, decimal

I'm trying to answer the question below:

> Use an array or ArrayList and generate 20 random numbers (Integer
>   values between 0 and 100. 100 not inclusive). The program should
>   perform the following tasks.
>
> 1. Write the numbers from the array or ArrayList to a file.
> 2. Read the numbers from the file and display them on the console in decimal, hexadecimal and binary.

So far I have the random generator working well, and the file is being written. As for re-reading the file and displaying the numbers from the file as hex, decimal and binary...I am completely lost. Here is that I have so far.

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class Write {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Random generator = new Random();

    ArrayList numList = new ArrayList();

    int n = 0;

    while( n < 20 ) {
      int numGen = generator.nextInt(100);
      numList.add(numGen);
      n++;
    }        

    String result = numList.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
    result = result.replace(",", " ");

    System.out.print(result);

    String filePath = "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/FileIOTest/coding_assignment.txt";
    File f = new File(filePath);
    FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream (f);

    DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(fileout);

    dataOut.writeBytes(result);

    dataOut.close();
  }      
}
```

Comment: If you are allowed to do this, `Integer` class has two methods that do this for you called `toBinaryString` and `toHexString`. If you are not allowed to use those there are lots of examples on here that show how to do it without. Look over in the related questions ->

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you have not started to write the code for Reading numbers from file.

Regarding reading the values, you can use BurreferReader to read numbers line by line. And then you can use String.split method to split the numbers into an array using `split(" ")`

Regarding converting int value to **Binary** and **Hex** mode, you can use the method `toBinaryString` and `toHexString` in `Integer` class, like

int i = 20;

```
System.out.println(i);//Print int value
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i)); //Print Binary string
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(i)); // Print Hex string
```

Output in Console is as follows:

```
20
10100
14
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try to complete the lines by yourself, so I only give you some basic input.

To read from file, three lines:

```
fileIn
dataIn
readBytes
```

These lines should be easy. To get the numbers, use

```
split
Integer.ParseInt
```

and to display, you may refer to

```
Integer.toHexString
Integer.toBinaryString
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert numbers to **binary** and **hexadecimal** from base 10, you can simply use the methods:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(n);
Integer.toHexString(n);
```

However, if you actually want to code these for yourself, try checking out the following website:
http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/toBaseK.html

It helps provide a simple algorithm that converts from base 10 to any other number base.